# Better use HashTable or switch case

Tags: c#, hashtable, switch-statement

I'm not sure which one is better. I need to parse each character of an input string and get a replacing string for the character. For some objects all alphanumeric characters are allowed so using switch/case will cause a lot of code and reduce readability and maintainability but I can use a static method. Using a HashTable also requires a lot of code

Using the static method:

```
 private static string EncodeChar(char c)
    {
        var symbols = string.Empty;

        switch (c)
        {
            case '0':
                symbols = "Test";
                break;
            case '1':
                symbols = "Hello";
                break;
            [...]
        }

        symbols;
    }
```

Using HashTable:

```
private static Hashtable table = CreateTable();

private static Hashtable CreateTable()
{
    var table = new HashTable();
    table.Add('0',"Test");
    table.Add('1', "Hello");
    [...]
    return table;
}

private static string EncodeChar(char c)
{
    return table.ContainsKey(c) ? table[c].ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

The Encode method:

```
public void Encode()
{
    string output = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 1; i < Data.Length; i++)
    {
        output = string.Concat(output, EncodeChar(Data[i]));
    }

    EncodedData = output;
}
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages concerning performance and memory allocation?

Comment: Is it that you have to choose between these methods? Or are you OK with trying out something else?

Comment: it's also okay to try something else :-)

Comment: Use `Dictionary<char, string>` rather than `HashTable` -- it is both considerably more efficient and less prone to accidental type errors.

Comment: you're right dictionary is better :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `HashTable`, because the code is more readable and maintainable: you could one day decide to load the subtitution strings from an XML file, so that you won't change the code to change the mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing is faster as you can directly access the 'encoded string'

for example, If you assume that all characters are '9', so it will have to evaluate 8 `if conditions` before executing the right `statement`, each time you process a character.

That's just a worst-case example while using the `switch()`

Comment: Switch statements jump directly to the correct case, they don't try each case out until it meets the right one. Internally the switch statement is effectively converted into a Dictionary, so it uses hashing anyways.

Comment: @RichK: The situation is somewhat more complex than you let on. Sometimes switch statements are converted to dictionaries, and dictionaries can, in some cases, try multiple elements in a bucket before they get the right one. Switch statements are sometimes compiled into jump tables which do jump directly to the correct code. And switch statements are sometimes compiled into what is effectively a series of if-then statements. Which technique the compiler chooses is an implementation detail. In this example the compiler would almost certainly choose a jump table.

Answer (score 0):

The switch code does the same thing as the alternative, but it's much more readable which should be the main concern here.

I would however use an abstract factory to get one of a number of different encoding implementations for different types of input.