# Fetch Multiple items from linq

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have below legacy code in my application and would like to optimize it. `arrayOfAttrValue` has unique attributes. Can I use LINQ to acheive the loop optimization? If so then can you please show me how?

```
foreach (AttrValue attr in arrayOfAttrValue)
{
    switch(attr.Attribute)
    {
        case Constants.Gender
            mymodel.Gender = attr.Value;
            break;
        case Constants.Identifier
            mymodel.AppIdentifier = attr.Value;
            break;
    }
}
```

My intention is not necessarily to use LINQ only. Any other way to minimize the loop would also help.

Thanks.

Comment: LINQ doesn't optimize. LINQ makes more readable (or at least more readable for certain persons)

Comment: What is the logic of this code? It can assign properties of model several times

Comment: ... and only the last `attr` would determine the value of `mymodel`

Comment: What make my question a worthless and deserve to get negative votes? Downvoters pls let me know

Comment: Is this code a performance bottleneck? Re-writing to use Linq will more than likely make this code slower.

Comment: @El Ronnoco i wont say it causes perfromance bottleneack. But we refactoring the legacy code and would like to do some optimization on the above code

Comment: Personally - I'd find something else to optimise :)

Comment: Perhaps you mean 'refactor' instead of 'optimise'. Are you trying to make your code more readable? Are you trying to make it use LINQ so that it looks like the read of your code? If so, consider rephrasing your questions to something like 'How can I refactor this code to use LINQ?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it in "true" LINQ because LINQ is about producing new objects from old objects. Here `mymodel` is a preexisting object that you want to modify.

You could use the [Array.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) or the [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) but

1. They aren't "true" LINQ and
2. The resulting code would be equivalent (a little slower because there would be a delegate)

Still, the downvoter probably wanted some LINQ, so I'll give some LINQ:

```
arrayOfAttrValue.All(attr => {
    mymodel.Gender = attr.Attribute == Constants.Gender ? attr.Value : mymodel.Gender;
    mymodel.AppIdentifier = attr.Attribute == Constants.Identifier ? attr.Value : mymodel.AppIdentifier;
    return true;
});
```

One less line, ignoring the `{}` lines.

Comment: @Downvoter, can you please add some <strike>valuable</strike>useless comment?

Comment: My intention is to not to use only LINQ. Any other way to minimize the loop would also help me.

Comment: @Al. That code is already minimal... unless you have some other problems (like the same code in hundred of different places). Its intentions are clear, the size i nearly the minimal possible (and probably minimal as number of characters), and it's the fastest.

Comment: @ xanatos it's the fastest -> Whether the code suggested by you or mine?

Comment: @Al. You probably have something more complex here... I can see it... But its outlines aren't well defined. You are deserializing something from a place to another, and you would like to make it more automatic, instead of having to repeat the same boilerplate code tens of times... Sadly that isn't the question you asked, and you didn't give enough details to build a response to the question you didn't ask.

Comment: @Al. depends on how many items you have in array. Depends on whether you have duplicate attributes there

Comment: @Ai Your code. It's perfect as it's (technically you should add a : after every line with case, and some break; at the end of every case, but these are details.)

Comment: I want to populate mymodel from arrayOfAttrValue (which has 100s of unique attributes) but avoid the loop equal to the list count. So shall I go with yours. Or should I wait for your update xanatos?

Comment: @Al. You should use the code you already have. Mine is probably slow as hell, and even more complex to maintain.

Comment: @Al. why you use array instead of dictionary? Use dictionary to avoid looping over all 100 attributes. That will give you best performance

Comment: @lazyberezovsky No, because `switch` could be based on an hashtable/jumplist, so it could still be faster (read the comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/9277474/613130 by Lippert)

Comment: @xanatos LINQ method 'All' will terminate as soon as it satisfies all the condition. But my code will run thru for all the elements even after populating mymodel. So how do you say your code is slow as hell?

Comment: @Ai. No, `All` is used as an hacked `ForEach`. The last line is a `return true;` that will make the `All` loop all the elements. The same hack can be done with `Any` and `return false`; As I've said, you can't really make a LINQ expression of your code. You can only hack something together that seems a LINQ expression.

Answer (score 1):

You have list of attributes, which represent key-value pairs. Natural way to keep such data structures is a dictionary. So, convert your input data format to dictionary:

```
var attributes = arrrayOfAttrValue.ToDictionary(a => a.Attribute, a => a.Value);
```

Or if each attribute is not unique in your array, dictionary creation will be more difficult, but that's data format you have. In order to make working with your data easier you should convert them to handy format:

```
var attributes = arrayOfAttrValue
                   .GroupBy(a => a.Attribute)                
                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a => a.Value).Last());
```

After creating attributes dictionary, you can simply check if you have value for attribute and assign that value to model property. Attributes retrieving now simple and clear for any reader:

```
if (attributes.ContainsKey(Constants.Gender))
    model.Gender = attributes[Constants.Gender];

if (attributes.ContainsKey(Constants.Identifier))
    model.AppIdentifier = attributes[Constants.Identifier];
```

Comment: @Downvloter, can you please add some valuable comments?

Comment: +1 @Downvoter Me too thanks! ah, lazyberezovsky, I'll say that your code is the most overblown unreadable thing I've ever seen in the last 5 minutes. Still +1 because the intention is there :-) Perhaps you could have directly used a `ToLookup()`

Comment: @xanatos I thought about lookup, but original logic uses only last value. About overblown code. That depends on what `arrayOfAttrValue` contains. If each value is unique, then dictionary creation will be simple as `var attributes = arrrayOfAttrValue.ToDictionary(a => a.Attribute, a => a.Value);` Updated code with this sample

Comment: You can still use Last() `inside` the foreach, instead of doing two operations of "grouping/hashing" (the GroupBy and the ToDictionary)... and for overblown... It was ironic, but your code changed 6 lines of perfectly readable code to 7 slower lines of difficult to read code. If I didn't know what your code should do, it would take to me 5 minutes to crack it, and then for another 20 minutes I would still be unsure if there are invisible side effects... In the end persons ask LINQ, they receive LINQ...

Comment: @xanatos dictionary makes intent clear. Look at model properties assignment part - its completely clear to any reader. Without understanding last or first or switch or foreach logic (I even don't talk about performance here). If creating of dictionary looks overblown to you, then you have input data in bad format. Moving `last()` inside foreach just pushes bad input data format further in application. And you should separate processing them from other application logic. Anyway, I believe my second dictionary creation will do the job (it's just weird OP code, not input data problem)

Comment: No no... It was the Group + ToDictionary that was a little excessive... and a little unreadable. The simple ToDictionary is quite readable (but hope that Attribute isn't nullable)

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky , Converting my array to dictionay(in a web appliation - MVC) for each action metho, I dont think its good idea. Also its old code and my leaders dont welcome to changes the data structure (from list to dic) sadly

Comment: @Al. I'm talking about using dictionary instead of array. Not about converting.

Comment: Got you. Thank you for ur input – lazyberezovsky

Answer (score 1):

No need to do the loop manually in code, you can do it simply with `.LastOrDefault()`:

```
mymodel.Gender = arrayOfAttrValue
    .Where(attr => attr.Attribute == Constants.Gender)
    .Select(attr => attr.Value).LastOrDefault() ?? mymodel.Gender;
mymodel.AppIdentifier = arrayOfAttrValue
    .Where(attr => attr.Attribute == Constants.Identifier)
    .Select(attr => attr.Value).LastOrDefault() ?? mymodel.AppIdentifier;
```

The `?? mymodel.Gender` makes sure we're not setting it to `Default(T)` (i.e. `null`) in a situation where it was otherwise set to a value previously. This then matches the functional logic of your initial question.

Doing it this way makes it very clear what you are trying to do. Of course this approach means that you're looping over the array twice, however if your array is actually an array then this performance cost will be very small.

If you still have performance issues with this then you probably want to consider using a better data structure than an `arrayOfAttrValue` (something that is index accessable by `Attribute` such as a `Dictionary<,>`).

Comment: This seems to work but loop twice? Looks like it's not very efficient.

Comment: @KingKing looping twice is not always a bad thing, each loop is doing very little work, the only overhead of doing the loop twice is that you run the enumerator twice. However as `arrayOfAttrValue` is likely an `Array` the enumerator will be very quick, as such the performance hit is minimal. If you were getting many more properties this way I would strongly suggest a dictionary etc, but it still depends on how many unique values of `.Attribute` there are. I agree Linq isn't really needed in this case but the question asked for a Linq answer and it does make the logic very clear.